# Append text from HTML to XML

Tags: html, xml, forms, appendchild

G'day,

As a part of my assignment, I have to store the details entered by a user in a registration form into an XML document.

I have managed to do that BUT the problem is when a new user registers, the old details are over-written with the details of the new user. So, there is ONLY 1 user details in the XML document in the end.

I was wondering if there's any way to save the details of new user while "preserving" the old details.

Any help is appreciated :)

HTML Code -

```
<form id="rego" name="rego" method="get" action="register2.php">  
<table width="719" border="0">
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Email Address</div></td>
  <td><label for="email"></label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50"  /></td>
</tr>
  <td width="376"><div align="right">First Name</div></td>
  <td width="333"><label for="firstName"></label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="15"  /></td>
  <td><div id="underInput"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div align="right">Last Name</div></td>
  <td><label for="lastName"></label>
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" maxlength="20"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div align="right">Phone Number</div></td>
  <td><label for="phoneNumber"></label>
  <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" maxlength="10"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<tr>
  <td><div align="right">Password</div></td>
  <td><label for="password"></label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  maxlength="30"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div align="right">Re-type password</div></td>
  <td><label for="confirmPassword"></label>
  <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" maxlength="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/><!--onclick="saveForm();"--></td>
</tr>
```

PHP Code (I'm using DOM) -

```
<?php
    $CustomerEmail = $_GET["email"];
    $CustomerFName = $_GET["firstName"];
    $CustomerLName = $_GET["lastName"];
    $CustomerPhoneNumber = $_GET["phoneNumber"];
    $CustomerPassword = $_GET["password"];
    $CustomerConfirmPassword = $_GET["confirmPassword"];


    $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');

    $root = $doc->createElement('customers');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

    $customer = $doc->createElement('customer');
    $customer = $root->appendChild($customer);

    $email = $doc->createElement('email');
    $email = $customer->appendChild($email);
    $valueEmail = $doc->createTextNode($CustomerEmail);
    $valueEmail = $email->appendChild($valueEmail);

    $fName = $doc->createElement('firstname');
    $fName = $customer->appendChild($fName);
    $valueFName = $doc->createTextNode($CustomerFName);
    $valueFName = $fName->appendChild($valueFName);

    $lName = $doc->createElement('lastname');
    $lName = $customer->appendChild($lName);
    $valueLName = $doc->createTextNode($CustomerLName);
    $valueLName = $lName->appendChild($valueLName);

    $phone = $doc->createElement('phone');
    $phone = $customer->appendChild($phone);
    $valuePhone = $doc->createTextNode($CustomerPhoneNumber);
    $valuePhone = $phone->appendChild($valuePhone);

    $password = $doc->createElement('password');
    $password = $customer->appendChild($password);
    $valuePassword = $doc->createTextNode($CustomerPassword);
    $valuePassword = $password->appendChild($valuePassword);

    $confirmPassword = $doc->createElement('confirmpassword');
    $confirmPassword = $customer->appendChild($confirmPassword); 
    $valueConfirmPassword = $doc->createTextNode($CustomerConfirmPassword);
    $valueConfirmPassword = $confirmPassword->appendChild($valueConfirmPassword);


    $doc->save('customer2.xml');
    ?>
```

I apologise for any inconvience.

Comment: You can always append data to an xml. But can you please provide details of the technology you are using manipulate your xml? posting some code would also be of greate assistance

Comment: I'm taking values of the textboxes from HTML using GET method and passing them to a PHP file which appends the value as child to each tag. It's all simple stuff.
I'm sorry but I thought the code is not required here. If you still want, I can post some code. 
Thank you :)

Comment: More details are needed. We need to see the code so we can help figure out the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added the code now.

Comment: @melc The code is up.

Comment: @jrock2004 The code is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your existing file, before creating a new one each time and override the previous.

```
    .....
    $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');

    if($xml = file_get_contents( 'customer2.xml')){
      $doc->loadXML( $xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
      $root=$doc->getElementsByTagName('customers')->item(0);
    }else{
      $root = $doc->createElement('customers');
      $root = $doc->appendChild($root);
    }

    $customer = $doc->createElement('customer');
    $customer = $root->appendChild($customer);
    .....
    $doc->save('customer2.xml');
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much, kind sir.
I apologise for any inconvience caused before.